# openafs-client fails to upgrade on newest kernel 3.13.0-32 (ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, kernel

This morning my Ubuntu told me to do some updates, then in the end I had a msg that I should also do some HW support updates. And so I did.

During the upgrade I saw there was some problems with the openafs-client. After restarting the puter openafs-client didn't work. After rebooting on the previous version openafs-client works, but what should I do to get it working on the latest kernel 3.13.0-32?

Some facts:

`uname -a` :

```
Linux RD0022805 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:50:54 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Message when I do `service openafs-client start`:

```
*AFS module /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/fs/openafs.ko does not exist.
Not starting AFS.  Please consider building kernel modules using
instructions in /usr/share/doc/openafs-client/README.modules*
```

Maybe I only have to get the missing lib module to get it working?

If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by installing the openafs PPA from *https://launchpad.net/~openafs/+archive/ubuntu/stable* and starting openafs:

`sudo /etc/init.d/openafs-client start`